# Spring LDAP, setting connection details in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

I want to set LDAP connection to list all users from AD.
I successfully accomplished this with information stored in XML

```
<ldap:context-source
url="ldap://<url>"
base="dc=example,dc=local"
username="<user>@example.local"
password="<pass>" />
```

But how I can set this informations from Java, not in XML?
Tried with:

```
LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
    ctxSrc.setUrl("ldap://<url>");
    ctxSrc.setBase("dc=example,dc=local");
    ctxSrc.setUserDn("<user>@example.local");
    ctxSrc.setPassword("<pass>");
LdapTemplate tmpl = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);
setLdapTemplate(tmpl);
```

But when runing

`List users = (List<User>) ldapTemplate.search(LdapUtils.emptyLdapName(), "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))", new UserAttributesMapper());`

I get **NullPointerExeption**. Runing that without setting up properties from java (i.e. reading from xml) everything works fine

Comment: Can you add exception stack trace?

Comment: Updated post with stack trance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try this

```
LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
    ctxSrc.setUrl("ldap://<url>");
    ctxSrc.setBase("dc=example,dc=local");
    ctxSrc.setUserDn("<user>@example.local");
    ctxSrc.setPassword("<pass>");

ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet(); // this method should be called.

LdapTemplate tmpl = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);
setLdapTemplate(tmpl);
```

Comment: thats it !
ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet(); needed to be called on LdapContextSource, I was calling it on template :) Thank you !